# Reindex / Change value of elasticsearch field

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, kibana

I have collected logfiles over a few weeks and found out that I had an ugly filed in my elastic db. I'm seperating the `/var/log/syslog` into `timestamp, host, log_process, message`. Now the puppet agents of all servers add a number to their process e.g.

```
Aug 29 17:33:00 host123 puppet-agent[22742]: (/Stage[main]/...
```

I changed the filter so it removes `[22742]` from all new logs but I want to remove it also from already processed logs.

With my search `GET /logstash-*/_search?q=log_process=puppet-agent\[` I can find all fields containing the wrong format but I'm getting confused with reindexing and / or (partial) updates. How does my update query has to look? Or is this even possible?

Regards

Comment: Have a look at the update API, you can probably remove a field with update_by_query and avoid reindexing. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: I did. But I couldn't find a propper way to change the field value.

Comment: Now it looks like this "_source": { "log_process": "puppet-agent[7159]"... but I want it to look like this "_source": {  "log_process": puppet-agent"

Comment: Can you post your update query? Also, I understood you wanted to delete a record, which you can do with remove. I don't understand what's going on. You want to remove parts of a field value or delete the value?